# How to pass EditText to another activity?

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Name.class);
intent.putExtra("key", et.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String str = intent.getStringExtra("key");
tv.setText(str);
```

From using above code I can get a string value at other activity, but I need `editText` object at another activity.

can anyone give Idea ?

Thanks

Comment: And why do you need to pass the `EditText` object to another `Activity`?

Comment: Can't come to understand why people wants EditText object instead of its value?

Comment: why you want to pass the editText to another activity ? can give proper reason.

Comment: did you want to update/modify the edittext object from other activity...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not send the ID and then use findViewByid() on the receiver Activity?  Hope this helps:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
String name="textView";
int value=EditText.getID();
intent.putExtra(name, value);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

On receiver Activity:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE=1;
private int id;
private EditText et;
private Intent i;

i = new Intent(this,Name.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
et = (EditText)findViewById(id);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if (data.hasExtra("textView"))
        {
            //Get the selected file.
            id = data.getExtras().getInt("textView");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm .. using a Singleton static class you can achieve the same. Store the reference to your edittext in the SingleTon class in one activity and the retrieve it back in another activity and achieve what you want to do. Thats' one of the possible work around in Java for your problem.

As far as android SDK is concerned you can't pass a view obj reference in Intent to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in spite of all yells about uselessness of sending `EditText` to `Activity` I would say it can be done. For instance declare your own class which extends `EditText` and also implement `Parcelable` interface

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText implements Parcelable
{
       //a lot of things to be done...
}
```

In this case you will be able easily send `MyEditText` as `Parcelable` to another `Activity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Name.class);     
MyEditText et=new MyEditText(this);
intent.putExtra("key", et);     
startActivity(intent);
```

For sure utility of this approach is still disputable.